# Servlet Filter for login a web-base application

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a web-base Application that require user to enter UserID and Password to login into "Home page". I guess my best bet is to use Servlet Filter to authenticate user to login WITHOUT typing UserID and Password.

Also web-base Application have own web.xml file which is I need to add:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>LoginAuth</filter-name>
<filter-class>my.package.name.ServletFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
...
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>LoginAuth</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping
```

And I also need to complete following .java :

```
package my.package.name;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet Filter implementation class ServletFilter
 */
@WebFilter("/LoginAuth")
public class ServletFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public ServletFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // place your code here


        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);

        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

As for testing, I'm using a simple html's form to press a 'Submit' button to pass the Java class, ideally is to press the button and should see the Home page of my application(already login)  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="BIG5">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="ServletFilter" method="post">


<input type="submit" value="Click me!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I see many examples, but most are using custom .jsp or html to get getAttribute UserID and Password, but in my case that I want using EXISTING web-base Application to login. Any idea how I can complete above codes? or any other guidance that I should try?

Let say:

web-based Application: http://192.168.1.2:8080/sample/welcome/

UserID = "admin"

Password= "password"